# Selenium WebDriver Python for l login test with valid and invalid test data

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

How, can implement the following case in Python?

I just can't figure out how to solve this problem.
I currently finish the case1.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWeMU.jpg)

CASE – 1 [ Enter Correct Username and Password ]

CASE – 2 [ Both Email and Password Fields are blank.]

CASE – 3 [ Email field is filled and Password field is blank. ]

CASE – 4 [ Email field is blank and Password field is filled ]

CASE – 5 [ Email and Password are entered wrong ]

CASE – 6 [ Email is wrong and Password is correct ]

CASE – 7 [ Email is correct and Password is wrong ]

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried till now? Please post the code

Comment: currently, i just can code the answer in java,but do not how to code in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DDT module in python to run your tests with parameterized inputs.
DDT allows you to multiply a test case by running it with different test data, making it appear as multiple test cases.

Something like below should work -

```
import unittest

from ddt import ddt, data, unpack

class TestOne(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    #Initialize your webdriver here

@data(('username1', 'pw1'), ('username2', 'pw2'))
@unpack
def test(self, username, password):        
    register_email.send_keys(username)
    password.send_keys(password)
    #asserts

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

For more details, check out [DDT (Data-Driven/Decorated Tests)](http://ddt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)